# Using CASSANDRA or HBASE with WSO2

Tags: database, cassandra, wso2, hbase

I would like to configure hbase or cassandra in WSO2 and use it in my project. Can you help me and give me a example.

Answer (score 0):

You can find details on how to configure HBase and Cassandra in https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Implementation+With+Different+Database+Types

This is for WSO2 DAS 3.1.0. Make sure you use the mentioned HBase and Cassandra versions.

Comment: Thank you for your help... I try it but after that how can I generate my database using the hbase and Cassandra.